# getting and setting cookie spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, cookies

I am using `@requestbody` and `@responsebody` annotations for my authentication method using Spring MVC. I want to know how can I get and set cookies in spring mvc.. I need to store username and password in my cookie, which I am getting through the `requestbody`. Also want to know how can I get this set cookie in the browser, the next time the user logs in. Also does the browser sends the cookie automatically with the request body ? To be specific I don't want to go for Spring Security Remember me option. I am new to spring framework so an example code would be highly appreciated.

**Ajax Code in JS**:

```
 var ajaxOptions = {
            type: callType,
            url: serviceCompleteUrl,
            /* Add if required.
            dataType: returnType */
            async: false,
            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                /*
                 * TODO: See if this is required
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                 */
                ajaxSuccess = true;
                serviceResponse = data;
                /*
                }
                 */
            },
```

in the service I am just returning the object which will be mapped onto the serviceResponse and could be used by JS..

Sample **code for service** :

```
  @RequestMapping("/login")
    public @ResponseBody LoginObject Login(@RequestBody LoginParameter request)
    {
       /* Code */
       return LoginObject;
    }
```

This is how I am returning the object from the service, which is then catched by the serviceresponse in js..

Comment: NEVER STORE PASSWORD (even username) IN COOKIES !

Comment: I am storing them in encrypted format.. with the necessary precautions in case an attacker gets hold of it.

Answer (score 0):

Never store passwords (even encrypted) in Cookies. To implement the **Remember me** functionality you desire, you follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12990591/960778)

**Update:**
You need the logic for saving data in cookies on JS side. After the call to the service returns `LoginObject`, use some `JS` or `jQuery` code (like `document.cookie="key=" + value;`) to store data in cookies.

Comment: this is the reason I mentioned that I am using requestbody and responsebody annotations. Want to set cookies using them..

Comment: what I am doing is that I am making an ajax call from js to the service.. the service then processes the request and returns the response as an object back to the js.. so I am not using httpresponse in my app. Is there no way to set a cookie without using http response? coz the examples I found on internet had httpresponse in them..

Comment: Please share a sample code so that we can know exactly what your are doing and with what you need help. Kindly update your question with a short code where you make AJAX call to the service. And the service side code which responds to this request.

Comment: found this as a way to solve the problem that I am facing but I don't know how to implement the prehandle() method in interceptor.. Do you have any input on this ??http://mjremijan.blogspot.in/2012/06/spring-not-setting-cookie-on-ajax.html